# How to Unset the proxy from Windows command prompt permanently?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, http-proxy

I have set the proxy in my Windsows 7 cmd using the below commands

```
C:\> setx HTTP_PROXY http://username:password@proxy.example.com:1234
C:\> set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:5678
```

Now I'm trying to remove it by using the below commands,

```
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
```

This works only in the current command prompt session, when I open new cmd my old proxy urls are set again, I have to use     set http_proxy= again to remove it. How to remove this proxy settings permanently?

Comment: `setx HTTP_PROXY ""`?

Comment: Thanks this worked!.. I was trying with setx HTTP_PROXY="" which caused a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete variables in the current `cmd` instance, do this:

```
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
```

or (even better):

```
set "http_proxy="
set "https_proxy="
```

To delete variables for future `cmd` instances, do this:

```
setx http_proxy ""
setx https_proxy ""
```